# Can a new-expression "overflow" in the case of an array of int?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, language-lawyer, c++17

What is guaranteed to happen if you write `int *p = new int[SIZE_MAX];`? An exception is thrown? Or is it possible that the underlying `operator new[]` function is called with an argument computed as `SIZE_MAX * sizeof(int)`, with a possible unchecked overflow (modulo reduction)?

In C++17 ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf))  § 6.9.2 [basic.compound]  ¶ 2:

> Constructing a type such that the number of bytes in its object representation exceeds the maximum value representable in the type `std::size_t` (21.2) is ill-formed.

What are the consequences of an "ill-formed" type? Undefined-behaviour?

Let's assume `sizeof(int)` is greater than `1`. Is the following program well-formed, and guaranteed to throw an exception?

```
#include <cstdint> // SIZE_MAX
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t

int main() {
    std::size_t size_max = (SIZE_MAX);
    int *pointer = new int[size_max];
}
```

Or do I have to perform the following overflow detection?

```
#include <cstdint> // SIZE_MAX
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <new>     // std::bad_alloc

bool mul_overflow (std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
    std::size_t size_max = (SIZE_MAX);
    return a > (size_max / b);
}

int main() {
    std::size_t size_max = (SIZE_MAX);
    if (mul_overflow (size_max, sizeof(int)))
        throw std::bad_alloc ();

    int *pointer = new int[size_max];
}
```

The intent is to avoid an integer overflow in an optimized but standard conforming implementation, which may perform the multiplication without checking for modulo reduction, if the standard says that what happens in this case is implementation-defined (or undefined/unspecified behaviour).

Side notes:

- I say 'overflow' even though unsigned integer types do not overflow. It means 'modulo reduction' in this post.
- *new-expression* is defined in C++17 ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)) § 8.3.4 [expr.new] ¶ 1.
- This is a 'language-lawyer' question.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph you are citing talks about *types*.

I.e. you can't have a type `T` with `sizeof(T) > SIZE_MAX`. This doesn't concern `new` and should be diagnosed by the compiler at the compilation phase.

The behavior of `new` is explained in different place.
Since C++11, there exists special exception type `std::bad_array_new_length` that the implementation should throw if the size is erroneous. here is the relevant quote from the standard:

[[expr.new]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#8.6.2)

> The expression in a noptr-new-declarator is erroneous if:
>
> - (8.1) the expression is of non-class type and its value before converting to std::size_­t is less than zero;
> - (8.2) the expression is of class type and its value before application of the second standard conversion ([over.ics.user]) is less than
>     zero;
> - (8.3) its value is such that the size of the allocated object would exceed the implementation-defined limit; or
> - (8.4) the new-initializer is a braced-init-list and the number of array elements for which initializers are provided (including the
>     terminating '\0' in a string literal) exceeds the number of elements
>     to initialize.
>
> If the expression is erroneous after converting to std::size_­t:
>
> - (8.5)
>     if the expression is a core constant expression, the program is ill-formed;
> - (8.6)
>     otherwise, an allocation function is not called; instead
>
>   - (8.6.1)
>       if the allocation function that would have been called has a non-throwing exception specification ([except.spec]), the value of the
>       new-expression is the null pointer value of the required result type;
>   - (8.6.2)
>       otherwise, the new-expression terminates by throwing an exception of a type that would match a handler ([except.handle]) of
>       type std​::​bad_­array_­new_­length.

So this is expected behavior. However, keep in mind that your `operator new` overload would only receive the final `size_t` (i.e. after all the calculations), so you don't need to/can't do modulo reduction.

When implementing your own `operator new` (8.5) should be taken care of by the compiler and you'll only need to take care of (8.6).

Comment: This is what I suspect, but this is a 'language-lawyer' question, and I would like to be able to prove it with quotes from the standard.

Comment: @RalphS I've added relevant quotes from the standard

Comment: From [expr.new]: "The _new-expression_ attempts to create an object of the [...] _new-type-id_ " . Therefore, why would the requirements in [basic.compound] be irrelevant? It seems _new-expression_ operates on a **type**.

Comment: Thank you for inserting quotes from the standard, but I already read those parts a dozen times before posting, and I can't figure out how they guarantee that the program examples I posted will throw an exception. For instance, in the program examples I posted, which case applies? The "core constant expression" case? Or the "throw std​::​bad_­array_­new_­length" case? Why?

Comment: @RalphS it's irrelevant in your case, yes. [basic.compound] forbids definition of types bigger than certain size (i.e. you can't have `struct Foo { int a[1ull << 62]; };`). `new[]` doesn't create new types, it just allocates memory for an array. [expr.new] describes what error conditions for this are and how to handle them.

Comment: @RalphS in the `(8.6)` applies, since in `new int[size_max];` `size_max` is not core constant expression. The example with core constant expression would be `new int[SIZE_MAX];`. It basically says: if you use invalid size constant, you program is ill-formed (the compiler would likely, but not surely, reject it), in other cases the error would be thrown at run-time.

You can see how they behave in godbolt/wandbox or compiling and running them yourself.